# Getting drive info from a remote computer

Tags: c#, remote-desktop, driveinfo

I can view a remotly connected pc from this **article**:[Remote Desktop using c-net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET) . but i dont need it. I just have to connect with that pc and get the free space data of C drive. How could i do this? I can connect to a remote desktop. I can get driveInfo using IO namespace. but how to combine them?

Comment: Why use a remote desktop client if you don't need to remote desktop? I'd suggest looking at WMI for this - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12603641/1220971) for how.

Answer (score 26):

Use the [`System.Management` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dwd0y33x.aspx) and [`Win32_Volume` WMI class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa394515.aspx) for this.  You can query for an instance with a `DriveLetter` of `C:` and retrieve its `FreeSpace` property as follows:

```
ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath() {
    NamespacePath = @"root\cimv2",
    Server = "<REMOTE HOST OR IP>"
};
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path);
string condition = "DriveLetter = 'C:'";
string[] selectedProperties = new string[] { "FreeSpace" };
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_Volume", condition, selectedProperties);

using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
using (ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get())
{
    ManagementObject volume = results.Cast<ManagementObject>().SingleOrDefault();

    if (volume != null)
    {
        ulong freeSpace = (ulong) volume.GetPropertyValue("FreeSpace");

        // Use freeSpace here...
    }
}
```

There is also a `Capacity` property that stores the total size of the volume.

Comment: Don't I have to pass any authentication in path?

Comment: That depends on your environment.  Credentials and other security options can be set using the [`scope.Options` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.managementscope.options.aspx), which is an instance of the [`ConnectionOptions` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.connectionoptions.aspx).

Comment: What is the freeSpace? Is it in Bit?

Comment: I found out it's in Byte. but the information isn't accurate. For example the C: drive has 56.5 GB free in the server but the code is showing me 62GB.

Comment: @Si8 Where are you getting the "accurate" free space from?  Windows Explorer?  Are you calculating free gigabytes using `freeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024` or, I presume, `freeSpace / 1000 / 1000 / 1000`?

Comment: Yes... I +1 because I was using Google's converter it was not working correctly but when I applied the proper calculations it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After losing a full day trying to make WMI work remotely without success I discovered an alternative using performance counters. Simply check the `Free Megabytes` counter in the `LogicalDisk` category using the desired drive letter (appended by ":") as the instance name to get an updated reading of the drive's available free space:

```
"LogicalDisk(C:)\Free Megabytes"
```

You can access it programmatically in C# through the [PerformanceCounter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter?view=net-5.0).

For accessing it remotely you'll need to specify the server name to the [performance counter class constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_PerformanceCounter__ctor_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_) and the impersonated account must be added to the "Performance Monitor Users" group:

```
net localgroup "Performance Monitor Users" %username% /add
```

Comment: It'd be helpful, if not necessary, to provide the `PerformanceCounter` code that queries this value.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the vb.net equivalent in case you need to translate it.

```
        Dim path = New ManagementPath With {.NamespacePath = "root\cimv2",
                                          .Server = "<REMOTE HOST OR IP>"}
    Dim scope = New ManagementScope(path)
    Dim condition = "DriveLetter = 'C:'"
    Dim selectedProperties = {"FreeSpace"}
    Dim query = New SelectQuery("Win32_Volume", condition, selectedProperties)
    Dim searcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query)
    Dim results = searcher.Get()
    Dim volume = results.Cast(Of ManagementObject).SingleOrDefault()
    If volume IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim freeSpace As ULong = volume.GetPropertyValue("FreeSpace")

    End If
```